# How is it possible to place picture on a page diagonally, so that the picture would remind a shape of a diamond?

Tags: html

How is it possible to place picture on a page, but not vertically or horizontally, but diagonally, so that the picture would remind a shape of a diamond?

Is it possible in HTML at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [CSS3 transform property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), which, however, is not supported in IE below 9, to rotate the image 45 degrees.

Comment: Better documentation from the official websites: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/transform) and [Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh393506#_CSS3_2D_Transforms) w3schools is frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS3 transformation as a solution:

```
.rotate_7deg_class {
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */    
}
```

Lower versions of IE is not supported by this.

Alternatively, you can create a PHP script, which dinamically generates a rotated version of the image, but that's a bit harder.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- Use CSS3 transform to rotate the picture. It doesn't need image editing but not compatible with some browsers (e.g: IE)
- Rotate the picture in picture editor (GIMP, Photoshop, etc.), and give it a transparent background.